# Set IFS to two bytes value in Bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, string

How to set IFS to two bytes value in Bash ?

```
IFS=',;'
```

will delimit each part of which resides between two simple `,` and/or simple `;` instead of `,;` as a delimiter
How is emulated/workaround way, so that gives a solution? Thanks before

Comment: It's not clear (to me) whether you want either `,` or `;` to be a delimiter, or the two character combination `,;` to be the delimiter

Comment: @roaima since they describe that using `IFS='.,'` will "delimit each part of which resides between two simple , and/or simple ; instead of ,; as a delimiter", I think the OP wants to set the string `,;` as the delimiter. Hence the "two bytes" in the title.

Comment: @Terdon I still can't see it. `word ,; word ,; word` or `word , word ; word`?

Comment: Presumably, `word ,; word ,; word` @roaima, otherwise the `IFS=',;'` which they have in the question would work.

Comment: the bash manual says "The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter," so as you say , a workaround is needed. how about you change the double character you 'd like to use as a delimiter in a single character, perhaps in a temp file or in the memory?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse characters and bytes, since there are multi-byte characters. In your example, a character is a byte, but an `ö` may be a multi byte character in some locales.

Comment: What is the need? Do you really need this in bash? Can't `awk -F',;'  '.......'` be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFS` is a set of single-character separators, so with `IFS=,;`, either of `;` or `,` would work as a separator, and `a,b,;c;d` would have five fields. If you want to use just the combination `,;` as a single separator, you'll have to do it manually. One way is to replace that `,;` pair with some single character you then do put in `IFS`:

```
s='a,b,;c;d'
IFS=#
fields=(${s//,;/#})
```

`${s//,;/#}` replaces all substrings `,;` with `#`, and the unquoted expansion then splits  the result. Now the array `fields` contains `a,b` and `c;d`. Note that it will also use the resulting words as globs (filename wildcards). You may want to prevent that with `set -f` / `set -o noglob`, but note that as well assigning to `IFS`, that has a global effect.

Or you could use `sed`, especially if you have a pipe there to begin with:

```
sed -e 's/,;/#/g'
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, agh, I meant to put the `@` there. But no matter, you'd already posted the Zsh solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to `zsh` instead of `bash` and use its `s` (for `s`plit) parameter expansion flag:

```
$ string='foo,;bar,;,;baz'
$ words=("${(@s[,;])string}")
$ typeset -p words
typeset -a words=( foo bar '' baz )
```

Note that it's *splitting* not *delimiting*, `foo,;` would be split into `foo` and the empty string, not just `foo` like `bash`'s IFS splitting would (with single characters only).

Also note that in `bash` (and `zsh`, but not all shells), word splitting is done on the *characters* of `$IFS`, not *bytes*. For instance, with `IFS='é'`, `Stéphane` would be split into `St` and `phane` even in locales where `é` is encoded on two bytes (like in those locales where the charmap is UTF-8, the most common these days).

Comment: A shell that does  not support multi-byte characters may be called basically POSIX compliant for tiny embedded systems, but is "illegal" on a platform that claims UNIX compatibility. So using `dash` as system shell degrades a platform. BTW: `ksh88`. `ksh93`, `yash`  the `Bourne Shell` and `bash` support multi byte characters and thus allow things like `IFS=ö` on multi byte locales. BTW: my test script for multi byte support fails with `dash`, `mksh` and `zsh`.

Comment: @schily, note that both ksh93 and bosh fail on `bosh -c 'IFS=é; echo "$*"' sh St phane` (in multibyte locales (not tested with the latest bosh though)).

Comment: @schily, still a problem with bosh 2020/10/07 a+.

Comment: I am not sure what you like to test with that command, but you need to remove the double quotes for a test for multi byte support and you would need to write your name completely including the é. Result: one space -> multi byte support present. two spaces -> no multi byte support.BTW: the Bourne Shell added the basics for multi byte support in 1988 and completed it in 1993

Answer (score 2):

A bash (version 4.3+) function:

```bsh
split() {
    local string=$1 fs=$2
    local -n fields=$3
    fields=()
    while [[ $string =~ (.*)"$fs"(.*) ]]; do
        fields=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${fields[@]}" )
        string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    done
    fields=( "$string" "${fields[@]}" )
}
```

usage:

```bsh
$ string="field1,;field2,field2b,;field3a;field3b,;,;field4"
$ split "$string" ",;" result
$ declare -p result
declare -a result=([0]="field1" [1]="field2,field2b" [2]="field3a;field3b" [3]="" [4]="field4")
```

It will fail, like many naive attempts to implement CSV parsing, with the separator enclosed in quotes:

```bsh
$ split 'Thoughtfully, he said "Hello, friend."' , x
$ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="Thoughtfully" [1]=" he said \"Hello" [2]=" friend.\"")
```